# Using a serializable column and having it resave with incorrect values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using something similar to the following structure for a model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :frag, Hash
  attr_accessible :name, :frag
end
```

The frag value is a text field and is a precomputed hash that we can then render via to_json. The problem I am having is that when I save, it resaves the frag value even if it has not changed and it's clear that there is some corruption because it sometimes comes back as a String rather than a Hash.

```
1.9.3-p547 :004 > u=User.first
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Blax", frag: {:name=>"Black Monday"}, created_at: "2014-07-17 01:04:27", updated_at: "2014-07-17 01:10:52"> 
1.9.3-p547 :005 > u.name="Joe"

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "name" = 'Joe', "updated_at" = '2014-07-17 01:11:29.281133', "frag" = '---
:name: Black Monday
' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
   (1.3ms)  commit transaction
```

Is there any way to tell rails to bypass saving unchanged values so that it will not try to resave the frag value if it has not changed? It's to the point where I'm thinking of creating a separate class to just manage this cached value.

I really want this:

```
   (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "name" = 'Joe', "updated_at" = '2014-07-17 01:11:29.281133', "frag" = '---
:name: Black Monday
' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
```

to be this:

```
   (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "name" = 'Joe', "updated_at" = '2014-07-17 01:11:29.281133'
   'WHERE "users"."id" = 1
```

#### Edit 1

I think the issue is that it applies to_yaml to it each time and wrecks the format eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here in your question.

## 1. Your serialized value is being updated on every save.

This is actually the intended behavior, and you can read about it [in the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/992fda16ed662f028700d63a8dcbd1837f1d58ab). But, let me elaborate:

The way ActiveRecord knows whether an attribute has changed is because a setter method was used.

```
  user = User.first
  user.frag = {new: 'hash'} # this calls the setter method User#frag=
  user.frag_changed?        # => true
```

However, when serializing a hash, for example, it's very possible for frag to change *without* calling the setter:

```
  user = User.create name: 'new', frag: {a: 'hash'}
  user.frag # => {a: 'hash'}
  user.frag[:that] = 'changed'
  user.frag # => {a: 'hash', that: 'changed'}
```

So. Because of this problem, and (I'm guessing) because the performance of doing a full comparison to the current db value was deemed too expensive, what you are seeing is very intentional.

*FYI, in Rails 4.1, it does compare the values and this problem goes away.*

Also, if I'm understanding your concern, I do not think this is the cause of your actual problem, which I'll get into next.

## 2. Your serialized value is "sometimes coming back as a String"

This I'm much less sure about. I do know that your Hash is being serialized as a yaml string - that's how serialize works. It would be very helpful if you showed a more concrete example of this "coming back as a string" problem. Maybe you're right and it's yamlifying your value over and over, but that would surprise me under normal use.

Comment: thx - I agree with everything in your first point. I was saving pieces that was clearly being reserialized again `"here ia

Comment: sorry comment above was > 5 minutes, basically it was being recognized as a string so that subsequent save would re-serialize. I was saving complex hashes like nested hashes that would write out. That being said it worked > 90 % of the time. Looking around online, I saw some issues possibly with utf-8 and Ruby 1.9 (we were using 1.9.3 at the time but have subsequently moved to 2.1.2). Thx for answer - I'll accept but think there's some definite wonkiness in saving complex objects as YAML strings. Ended up serializing as JSON which seems to work